# Excel vba can't hide row

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that goes through rows and checks for duplicates. If there is a duplicate if should hide the row. But somewhy it doesn't hide it.

```
Function sumAll()

Dim firstRow As Long
firstRow = 5
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 1424
Dim aRow As Long

Dim totalDoubles As Long
totalDoubles = 0

Dim sumResult As Double
sumResult = 0
Dim previousValue As String

previousValue = -1
For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
    If Cells(aRow, 1).Value <> previousValue Then
        sumResult = sumResult + Cells(aRow, 2)
        previousValue = Cells(aRow, 1)
        Cells(aRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        totalDoubles = totalDoubles + 1

    End If
Next aRow
sumAll = sumResult
MsgBox ("end: " & totalDoubles)

End Function
```

I also tried `Sheets("Sheet name").Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden=True` but it gave no effect as well.

Comment: Declare the whole thing as `Sub sumAll()` ... `End Sub`. A function is a thing that takes parameters and returns a return value. What you're doing needs a sub. During a function execution you can not alter the worksheets / workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
Cells(aRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

to:

```
Rows(aRow).Hidden = True
```

**Note**: as @Rik Sportel mentioned, there's no reason for this to be a `Function` as you are not returning any values or objects from it, so it can be a regular `Sub`.

To make sure all your `Cells` and `Rows` are fully qualified with your `Worksheet` object, add the `With` statement:

```
With Sheets("YourSheetName")
    For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
        If .Cells(aRow, 1).Value <> previousValue Then
            sumResult = sumResult + .Cells(aRow, 2)
            previousValue = .Cells(aRow, 1)
            .Rows(aRow).Hidden = True
        Else
            totalDoubles = totalDoubles + 1
        End If
    Next aRow
End With
```